# Huawei Hair Segmentation Retuning Null value at getMask()

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

I'm working on a project where I have to change the hair color of a person's image and for this, I'm using Huawei Hair segmentation.

Here is the code of Analyzer which analyze the image.

```
val setting = MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory()
        .setExact(true)
        .setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.HAIR_SEG)
        .create()
    analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(setting)
    // Create an MLFrame by using android.graphics.Bitmap. Recommended image size: large than 224*224.
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.imgseg_foreground);
    val mlFrame = MLFrame.Creator().setBitmap(bitmap).create()
    val task: Task<MLImageSegmentation> = analyzer!!.asyncAnalyseFrame(mlFrame)
    task.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<MLImageSegmentation?> { imageSegmentationResult -> // Processing logic for recognition success.
        if (imageSegmentationResult != null) {
            this@SkinColorFragment.displaySuccess(imageSegmentationResult)
        } else {
            this@SkinColorFragment.displayFailure("imageSegmentationResult is null.")
        }
    })
        .addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e -> // Processing logic for recognition failure.
            this@SkinColorFragment.displayFailure(e.message!!)
        })
```

And here is the code of displaySuccess()

```
private fun displaySuccess(imageSegmentationResult: MLImageSegmentation) {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        displayFailure("bitmap is null.")
        return
    }
    // Here I get null value in getMask()
    if (imageSegmentationResult.getMasks() == null) {
        return
    }
    var processedBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    val pixels: IntArray = byteArrToIntArr(imageSegmentationResult.getMasks())
    processedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        pixels,
        0,
        bitmap!!.width,
        bitmap!!.width,
        bitmap!!.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    if (processedBitmap != null) {
        binding.imgHolder.setImageBitmap(processedBitmap)
    } else {
        displayFailure("bitmapFore is null.")
    }
}
```

and I get the null value here.

```
if (imageSegmentationResult.getMasks() == null) {
        return
    }
```

This is the ml kit sdk version I'm using

```
// Import the base SDK.
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:3.4.0.300'
// Import the multiclass segmentation model package.
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-multiclass-model:3.4.0.300'
// Import the human body segmentation model package.
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:3.4.0.300'
// Import the hair segmentation model package.
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-hair-model:3.4.0.300'
```

And this is the log info

> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.623 7423-7423/com.android.backgroundremover E/CountryCodeBean: getVendorCountry=UNKNOWN
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.624 7423-7423/com.android.backgroundremover E/CountryCodeBean: getSimCountryCode by not enableNetwork, countryCode=pk
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.701 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HaLogProvider: in common ha, BUILD_MODE is: APK
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.702 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HaLogProvider: forbiddenHiLog.getVenderCountry=UNKNOWN
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.702 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HaLogProvider: forbiddenHiLog openHa = false
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.702 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/ImgSeg_ImageSegImpl: accuracy:1,model:2,timeType:0
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.704 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HMSNativate: accuracy:1,modelKey:2,isVedio:0,scene:0
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.704 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HCLJNI: [HCL] 202112292 in runnet(). new.a. Elab: 1, MKey: 2, isVideo: 0, set: 0
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.704 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HCLJNI: [HCL] enter runnet().
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.707 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HCLJNI: [HCL] InputHeight,InputWidth: 1031, 688
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.715 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HCLJNI: [HCL] after resize, h: 289, w: 289.
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.721 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /general_model_executor.cpp CheckInputs(811)::"input size not match:2, 1"
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.721 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /general_model_executor.cpp Execute(868)::"check geBaseBuffInput failed"
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.721 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/AI_DDK_MSG: /ai_model_executor_manager.cpp Execute(698)::"aicp::IModelExecutor::Execute failed! ret:0xffffffff."
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.721 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/AI_DDK_MSG: Process(145)::"Model synchrous process failed: seg_1c.om"
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.722 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /HiAiModelManagerService.cpp Process(374)::"run seg_1c.om failed"
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.722 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HCLJNI: [HCL] Line 1611, run 1cModel failed, ret: 1.
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.722 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover I/HMSNativate: ---> mindSporeRunnet time = 18
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.723 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/HMSNativate: runnet fail
> 2022-04-29 13:58:31.723 7423-8129/com.android.backgroundremover E/ImageSegImpl: ProcessImage failed imageSliceDecteorParcel is null

I don't know why it's not working as I've extracted this code from the demo app and there it's working perfectly.

Comment: hi@Nabeel Ahmed, what was the ML kit SDK version? and could you please provide the detailed log info for us to check?

Comment: Hello @shirley, I updated my question. Kindly check it now.

Comment: Hi@Nabeel Ahmed, thanks for your feedback, looks like we cannot locate the issue based on the above info. Could you mind send a test demo for us to check? you can send it to hmscore@huawei.com, thanks!